# How to secure a namespace with passport js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Assume I have a route with the following namespace:

```
app.use('/logged', adminRoute);
```

Now, I have created the following passportjs function:

```
app.get('/logged/panel', function (req, res) {
  if (req.user === undefined) {
      res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
      res.render('/logged/panel', {
      user: req.user
  })
  }
});
```

This function checks wether the user is authenticated on the `/logged/panel` pattern.

I want to modify this function so it will perform checks on each get/post url pattern from `adminRoute`. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `express.Router`.

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(logged) return next();

  res.redirect('/login');
}

var loggedRouter = express.Router();
loggedRouter
  .use(ensureAuthenticated)
  .get('/panel', panelHandler)
  .get('/other', otherHandler);

var mainRouter = express.Router();
mainRouter.use('/logged', loggedRouter);

app.use(mainRouter);
```

You can include checking if user is logged inside `ensureAuthenticated` function. This middleware function will always be executed before `/logged/panel` and `/logged/other`.